# Parametrize Cucumber Runner class

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, runner

My runner class looks like this:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber", "json:target/cucumber.json" },
        glue = "glue path",
        features = "feature path",
        tags = {"@tags"}
        )
public class TestClass{
}
```

I want to know if there is a way to replace hard coded values like

```
glue = "**some path**", features = "**some feature**"
```

with constants or variables? Can you please help with this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can take a look [QAF gherkin client](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) it provides way to configure through xml file or through properties in property file.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your values as static final variable and you can use in the annotation.

```
public static final String glue = "glue"; in class Constants.java
```

Use it as

```
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber", "json:target/cucumber.json" },
        glue = Constants.glue,
        features = "feature path",
        tags = {"@tags"}
        )
```